# Multiple sitemaps.xml , multiple Websites But Single host

Tags: xml, sitemap, robots.txt

currently:
i have a pool of website which is developed in asp classic and vbscript by using different css and implementation on a single host in IIS .

their sitemap.xml is different from each other e.g.

`http://www.mysite1.com/sitemap-mysite1.xml`

`http://www.mysite2.com/sitemap-mysite2.xml`

`http://www.mysite3.com/sitemap-mysite3.xml`

but all the xml files place in one host `http://www.mysite1.com/`

how to set sitemaps of these sites ?? does robots.txt would help in this solution ?? if yes than wouldnt i give problem if i put entries like

`sitemap:http://www.mysite1.com/sitemap-mysite1.xml
sitemap:http://www.mysite2.com/sitemap-mysite2.xml
sitemap:http://www.mysite3.com/sitemap-mysite3.xml`

how search engine bot would differentiate in between these sitemaps ... ??

Answer (score 1):

What version of IIS are you using?  If it's IIS7 and it has URLRewrite enabled, then you could write some rewrite rules based on the incoming HTTP_HOST.

```
<configuration>
<system.webServer>
<rewrite>
<rules>
<rule name="Domain based sitemap forwarding" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true">
<match url="sitemap\.xml"/>
<conditions>
<add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="www\.(.*?)\.com"/>
</conditions>
<action type="Rewrite" url="/sitemap-{C:1}.xml"/>
</rules>
</rule>
</rewrite>
</system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

The above would rewrite http://www.mysite1.com/sitemap.xml to http://www.mysite1.com/sitemap-mysite1.xml etc.  although if you're on an older version of IIS that doesn't have URLRewrite it won't do anything.

Comment: mu IIS version is 6.0 and website is developed in asp classic and vb script. i dont  know where to put this code  ?? can u guide me little bit more

Comment: @NewbieFreak Sadly this isn't possible in IIS6 without third party plugins (e.g. Helicon's ISAPI Rewrite) and I'm guessing you may not have server access.    You could find out if your server has any URL rewriting facility, which would then allow you to rewrite sitemap.xml to other files.   The only other thing I can think of is if the server could execute server code on the XML file (then you could present it with different content or redirects), but again I really doubt this - your server admin may be able to help.

Answer (score 0):

You just put each sitemap in the root of each site. So .../public_html/site1/sitemap.xml and the search engines will find it.